# Product of functions in higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f,g :\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ be two functions.

My question is that whether we can define product of $f$ and $g$ the i.e $f.g$.

My teacher says no. I wonder why not? We can define inner product or pointwise product of terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether we can define a product of two elements in $\mathbb R^m$.

The answer is: It depends, what you like to get. Naturally, you can define a lot of operations which combines two elements of $\mathbb R^m$ like the dot product. You can even define operator from $\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$. Further, you can do it such that $(\mathbb R^m, +,\cdot)$ is a ring like $\mathbb Z$ by the componentwise multiplication.

But if you ask for a product $\cdot:\mathbb R^m\times\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^m$ such that $(\mathbb R^m, +,\cdot)$ forms a field then your teacher is right.